# How do I host my python functional flask app on firebase hosting?

Tags: python, firebase

I am attempting to host a python flask app on firebase. It is a fully functional app with a backend database and everything. Can someone guide me as to how this flask app can be hosted on using firebase.

Comment: Firebase hosts static content, not dynamic apps, last I checked. If you have all the services on your own, then you should be using GKE or GCE, assuming you want to stay with Google products

Comment: Or, what's wrong with Heroku based on your previous questions?

Comment: You can use render.com for free. It is almost similar to heroku, except that it is free

Answer (score 1):

As commented by OneCricketeer, Firebase hosting is used for hosting static content. You can use [Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions) to deploy your Flask API and then make API calls from your web app.

While Firebase hosting has [rewrites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites) which can technically have your API on same domain as hosting, I'm not totally sure if they work with Firebase Cloud Functions (wrapper around GCF) only or GCF (Python) as well.